# How to crop height of image when height is exceeded, without using px in order to allow responsive

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am using a php loop to pull in post articles from Wordpress and since the images vary in height I wish to add some css that guarantees the image height always stays the same, without distorting the photo.

Should I just fix the height at lets says 200px using object-fit and then use max-width to make it responsive or is there a better way to do this?

[image]

```css
.fonds-thumbnail-header {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="fonds-thumbnail-header">
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="fonds-thumbnail-header">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'medium', array(
            'class' => 'fonds-thumbnail-header',
            'alt' => get_the_title()
            ) );
        ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You could add an image size add_image_size and make it a specific size, then call it in your the_post_thumbnail

Comment: @HowardE Thank you didnt know about this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to [add image size](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)... Do this in your functions.php of your theme.

```
function dd_custom_image_sizes(){
    // 300 x 200 cropped center
    add_image_size( 'my_custom_thumb', 300, 200, array('center', 'center'));
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'dd_custom_image_sizes');
```

Since you're adding a new image size, after your site is already set up, you'll have to regenerate the thumbnails to get your new size applied.  This plugin [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) is what you should use.

After you run the plugin and have your new thumbs...

Then in your template, call that size:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'my_custom_thumb', array(
     'class' => 'fonds-thumbnail-header',
     'alt'  => get_the_title()
     ) );
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, somehow missed your reply, this is an even better solution.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should make it fix , and maybe for the image size you can try something like this at if( has_post_thumbnail() )

```
<div class="crop" style="
    background-image: url('test300x450.png');   
    width: 300px;   
    height: 300px; 
    background-position: center center; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;"> 
</div>
```